# PostgresSQL connection timeout when trying to connect from remote

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql, remote-server

I have a cloud server which I'm connected to, this server has `psql` client application installed. On my local machine I have docker and I launched a container with the following `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  timescale:
    container_name: timescaledb
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - timescale-volume:/home/postgres/pgdata/data
      - timescale-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - trade-net
networks:
  trade-net:
    name: trade-net

volumes:
  timescale-volume:
    name: timescale-volume
```

This means Postgres is being exposed at port `5432` on my local machine.

`docker ps` prints:

```
f719eac32ebc   ark-sql-timescale   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   timescaledb
```

my `pg_hba.conf` looks like that:

```
# IPv4 local connections:                                           
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5   
# IPv6 local connections:                                            
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5                                                 
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the   
# replication privilege.                                             
local   replication     all                                     trust 
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Thus I'm allowing all IPs both on IPv4 and IPv6 with a password connection.

My `postgresql.conf` file is also listening on all ports:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Now from my remote server I try to connect from the `psql` client into psotgresql which is running via docker on my local machine with:

```
psql -h my_local_public_ip -p 5432 -U postgres
```

But the connection hangs and times out. I'm not sure what I am still doing wrong here.

Comment: Hanging means a firewall.  PostgreSQL-specific problems will generate some other kind of error.

Comment: But my firewall is turned off on mac

Comment: try `host    all     all    all    scram-sha-256` on `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: To anyone stumbling on this, I had the similar issue where I had configured everything correctly, opened up port 5432 on my firewalls, and it still would just hang. The only thing that fixed it was I ran `sudo ufw disable`. I tried to connect and it worked. I ran `sudo ufw enable` and it still worked. So maybe try that and let me know if it works.